# How to create new elements with React mapping props

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs

I am trying to create elements with **React** dynamically but I can't seem to use `this.props` correctly it seems. What I currently have does not produce any new elements. I've tried looking at various other answers and mimicking them but without any luck.

```
React.createClass({
getDefaultProps: function() {
    var items = [];
    chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(result) {
        var keys = Object.keys(result);
        // get all the keys from chrome storage and add to array items
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            items.push(keys[i]);
        }
    })
    return {
        items: items
    }
},
render: function() {
    // display an element with name of key
    return (
        <div>
        {this.props.items.map(function loop(item, i) {
            return (<div>{item}</div>)
        })}
        </div>
    )
}
})
```

However when I substitute a literal array for `this.props.items`, I get new elements. Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

chrome.storage is asynchronous:

> It's asynchronous with bulk read and write operations, and therefore
>   faster than the blocking and serial localStorage API.

This means that the `getDefaultProps` finishes before the call comes back, and the initial state is `{ items: [] }`. To fix that, make the request to the storage in ['componentDidMount'](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount), and set the state when the data arrives:

```
React.createClass({

    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
            items: [] // initial is empty
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function() { // the component has be rendered for the 1st time
        chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(result) { // receive the items
            var keys = Object.keys(result);
            // get all the keys from chrome storage and add to array items
            for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                items.push(keys[i]);
            }

            this.setState({ items: items }); // set the state
        }.bind(this)) // bind the callback to the component's this, so you can use this.setState
    },

    render: function() {
        // display an element with name of key
        return (
            <div>
            {this.props.items.map(function loop(item, i) {
                return (<div>{item}</div>)
            })}
            </div>
        )
    }

})
```

Comment: This works perfectly if I define items in getInitialState, and use this.state.items.map in the render function. Thanks!